# How to dynamically process nested object in Javascript if I don't know what is the depth?

Tags: javascript

Sorry, I don't know how to word this question properly but basically, I have this nested object `nestedObj`. I want to dynamically process this object but the depth of the object is not fixed. So for example:

```
nestedObj = {  
    "property1":{
        "subProperty1": {  
            "data": "This is the data for property1 > subProperty1"
        }
    },

    "property2":{
        "subProperty1": {
            "anotherSubProperty1": {
                "data": "This is the data for property2 > subProperty1 > anotherSubProperty1"
            }
        },
        "subProperty2": {
            "anotherSubProperty1": {
                "data": "This is the data for property2 > subProperty2 > anotherSubProperty1"
            }
        }
    },

    "property3":{
        "subProperty1": {  
            "data": "This is the data for property3 > subProperty1"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to process this object in a `for of` loop where my end goal is to get the value of `data` of certain nodes. Now, the path to the value of each object nodes are defined in another object:

```
dataPath = {
    "property1": "subProperty1.data",
    "property2": "subProperty2.anotherSubProperty1.data",
    "property3": "subProperty1.data",
}
```

And then I used this `for of` loop to process them:

```
properties = ["property1", "property2", "property3"];
for(var property of properties) {
    path_to_data = dataPath[property].split(".");
    data = nestedObj[path_to_data[0]][path_to_data[1]];

    // Some other logic
}
```

Obviously, this only works for "property1" and "property3". I have to add special handling for all the objects that have more than 2 inner nodes. For large data with varying numbers of depth, it would not be ideal to manually add these special handlers. So my question is, in Javascript, is there any way for me to dynamically process nested object when I have the "path" to a certain node.

Comment: Will you have paths for more data or you want all the data without specifying paths

Comment: @MaheerAli I want only the data from the provided paths

Comment: @akmalhakimi1991 I've updated my answer. I hope I understood it correctly, if not please let me know and I will try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to get the value from object with a path

```js
const nestedObj = { "property1":{ "subProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property1 > subProperty1" } }, "property2":{ "subProperty1": { "anotherSubProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property2 > subProperty1 > anotherSubProperty1" } }, "subProperty2": { "anotherSubProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property2 > subProperty2 > anotherSubProperty1" } } }, "property3":{ "subProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property3 > subProperty1" } } }
const dataPath = { "property1": "subProperty1.data", "property2": "subProperty2.anotherSubProperty1.data", "property3": "subProperty1.data", }
let props = ["property1", "property2", "property3"];

const getValueFromObj = (obj,path) => path.split('.').reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a] || {}),obj);
let res = props.map(x => getValueFromObj(nestedObj,x+'.'+dataPath[x]))

console.log(res)
```

#### using `for..of`

```js
const nestedObj = { "property1":{ "subProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property1 > subProperty1" } }, "property2":{ "subProperty1": { "anotherSubProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property2 > subProperty1 > anotherSubProperty1" } }, "subProperty2": { "anotherSubProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property2 > subProperty2 > anotherSubProperty1" } } }, "property3":{ "subProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property3 > subProperty1" } } }
const dataPath = { "property1": "subProperty1.data", "property2": "subProperty2.anotherSubProperty1.data", "property3": "subProperty1.data", }
let props = ["property1", "property2", "property3"];

const getValueFromObj = (obj,path) => path.split('.').reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a] || {}),obj);

for(let prop of props){
  let data = getValueFromObj(nestedObj,prop+'.'+dataPath[prop]);
  console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This successfully gives the values based on the paths. However, in my original code, I have a lot more logic in the `for of` loop (e.g adding the value to a table using jQuery) . How do I do the same if I use your solution?

Comment: @akmalhakimi1991 See the updated answer and consider accepting the answer if you satisfied with it.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Object.keys` to loop through the `dataPath` object. Then you `split` the value and use it an a **for loop** and keep track of the `data`.

```js
let nestedObj = {
    "property1": {
        "subProperty1": {
            "data": "This is the data for property1 > subProperty1"
        }
    },

    "property2": {
        "subProperty1": {
            "anotherSubProperty1": {
                "data": "This is the data for property2 > subProperty1 > anotherSubProperty1"
            }
        },
        "subProperty2": {
            "anotherSubProperty1": {
                "data": "This is the data for property2 > subProperty2 > anotherSubProperty1"
            }
        }
    },

    "property3": {
        "subProperty1": {
            "data": "This is the data for property3 > subProperty1"
        }
    }
}

let dataPath = {
    "property1": "subProperty1.data",
    "property2": "subProperty2.anotherSubProperty1.data",
    "property3": "subProperty1.data",
}

let properties = ["property1", "property2", "property3"]
for (let property of properties) {
    let path = dataPath[property].split('.')
    let data = nestedObj[property]
    for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        data = data[path[i]]
        if (i + 1 === path.length) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP said in the comment _"I want only the data from the provided paths"_

Comment: @MaheerAli I'm working on editing my answer, that comment was made after my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

lodash's [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) does exactly what you want. You can check out the [source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/get.js) to see the implementation.

```
const nestedObj = { "property1":{ "subProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property1 > subProperty1" } }, "property2":{ "subProperty1": { "anotherSubProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property2 > subProperty1 > anotherSubProperty1" } }, "subProperty2": { "anotherSubProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property2 > subProperty2 > anotherSubProperty1" } } }, "property3":{ "subProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property3 > subProperty1" } } }
const dataPath = { "property1": "subProperty1.data", "property2": "subProperty2.anotherSubProperty1.data", "property3": "subProperty1.data", }
let props = ["property1", "property2", "property3"];

props.forEach(property => {
  const nestedObjAtProperty = nestedObj[property]; // { "subProperty1": { "data": "This is the data for property1 > subProperty1" } }
  const dataPathForProperty = dataPath[property]; // "subProperty1.data"

  const data = _.get(nestedObjAtProperty, dataPathForProperty); // "This is the data for property1 > subProperty1"
  console.log(data);
}
```